# Selecting empty string with Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Pretty simple requirement: I need to select a named column with an empty string in [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/). Something along the lines of:

```cs
myQuery.Select("new(Col1, Col2, '' AS Col3)");
```

This doesn't work, though. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *This doesn't work* part?

Comment: How about if you try like `myQuery.Select("new(Col1, Col2, @0 AS Col3)", string.Empty);`?

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I eventually solved it: You must use `""` instead of `''` for the empty string.

```cs
// Construct query string
string queryColumns = string.Join(
    ",",
    string.Join(",", regularColumns),
    string.Join(",", requiredFeatureColumns.Select(featureID => $"\"\" AS Feature_{featureID}")));

// Get base data
List<dynamic> clientData = await myQuery
    .Select($"new({queryColumns})")
    .ToDynamicListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

```
myQuery.Select("new(Col1, Col2, @0 AS Col3)", string.Empty);
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jBYIXn

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this because of some inherent SQL injection prevention that disallows string literals in queries?

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The only difference between your solution and OP's initial code is that the empty string value comes via parameter and is not baked into the query string. I can't see why a hardcoded query string would not work (the DB wouldn't mind), unless there is an active validator blocking the query from being run, and the most likely reason I can come up with is that it is an (admittedly imperfect) way of blocking people using string concatenation in their query strings, which opens the door to SQL injection. Since you knew the answer, I figured you might know the reason why this works and OP's didn't.

Comment: Hmm, that is a really good question but I am not really sure why OP's solution does not work.